# System.Web.HttpException: Pharmacy Not Found

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iframe, nopcommerce

I am trying to show a another website in my current website using iframe.

Below is the code I am using.

```
<iframe width="1016px" height="900" src="https://apps1.webconnectqs1.com/login.aspx?id=53" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

It is rendering nicely. And asking for login. When I enter my credentials in the page loaded iframe on any version of IE it gives me an exception.

Below is the exception details with stack trace.

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Pharmacy Not Found]
   Global.Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +2325
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.RaiseOnStart(EventArgs e) +8807124
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState() +237
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +504
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +66
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I am not sure what is wrong with it If i try to load `https://apps1.webconnectqs1.com/login.aspx?id=53` directly in IE it works fine and after trying in directly. Same page works fine on my website as well.
Its working on all other browsers as well.

Can any one help

Thanks,
Samee

Comment: Better talk with the host of the site you're logging into to.

Comment: but problem is its working fine when i hit the URL directly.

Comment: https://apps1.webconnectqs1.com/login.aspx?

Comment: can it be because of some sessions or cookies that ie is not allowing. I am confused what could be the problem

Comment: I think it's because by default cookies or sessions can't be shared between different applications or hosts(security) what's the of the "root" page (the page who contains iframe)

Comment: http://www.totalcarerx.com/webconnect